# Working with multiple custom variables on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, fork

I am a bit of a novice to Google Analytics and I have been trying to figure out the following problem for far too long now. So perhaps you can help me. Any asstitance would greatly be appreciated.

I have one website, powered by Fork CMS, with one blog section. Within the blog section there are, practically speaking, 4 different blogs, marked by four different categories. On the page 'Blogs' four links are provided, each to a page on which all the blogposts from one category are displayed.

The four categories are 'Painters' 'Fine Art Photographers', 'Visual Artists' and 'Multimedia Artists'.

What I would like to see in Google analytics is 
1) an overview of all traffic on the site minus all the trafic to the blogs,
2) an overview of all the traffic to the blog 'Painters',
3) an overview of all the traffic to the blog 'Fine Art Photographers',
4) an overview of all the traffic to the blog 'Visual Artists' 
5) an overview of all the traffic to the blog 'Multimedia Artists'

I think I have figured out how to do 2-5, but I do not have a clue about the first one. How can I create a custom variable which takes all site traffic - 2 to 5...?

My GAcode right now:

```
   <script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);

    //custom variable for categories
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'Painters','3'],                
    ['_setCustomVar',2,'Fine Art Photographers','3'],['_setCustomVar',3,'Visual          
    Artists','3'],['_setCustomVar',4,'Multimedia Artists','3']);

    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'mydomain.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be to use a different scope, i.e.:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'Overview',2],
```

refer to:

[image: scope]

from [GA Link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables)